# a temp table for updating the values, getting error message saying 'temp table0' already exists, how to navigate this?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a VBA query in Access database for creating a temp table for updating the values, however I am getting error message saying 'temp table0' already exists, how to navigate this?

I am getting error message in 'CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql'

rs2.Close 'Close the recordset
            Set rs2 = Nothing 'Clean up

```
        'Create temporary tables

        Dim tableFlag As String
        tableFlag = "Treaty"
        For x = 1 To 2
            If (rs1![Prems/Claims] = "Premium") Then
                If (tableFlag = "Treaty") Then
                    strSql = "SELECT [Premiums " & tableFlag & "].ID, [Premiums " & tableFlag & "].[Pricing Segment]"
                    For i = 0 To columnsCount - 1 ' loop through all boolean atributes
                        strSql = strSql & ", [Premiums " & tableFlag & "].[" & boolAtrName(i) & "]"
                    Next
                    strSql = strSql & " INTO [tempTable " & tablesCount & "] FROM [Premiums " & tableFlag & "] WHERE [GDS Version] = " & rs1!ID & ";"

                    'Execute temporary table string

                    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strSql

                    'Add column percentage to table
                    CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE [tempTable " & tablesCount & "] ADD COLUMN Percentage double, Identifier Text"

                    'Update values in column percentage
                    Set rs2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM [tempTable " & tablesCount & "];")
```

Comment: You really need to include enough code into your question so that we can see how you are assigning the value to your `tablesCount` variable.  Without that code, we can't tell what is wrong.  (And, preferably, also include the code where you are deleting the temporary tables when you are finished with them.)

Comment: Why do you need code to create table? If this table structure will always be the same, manually create and save the table. Then just INSERT and DELETE records in the procedure. Table is permanent, records are temporary.